# angular2 wait for error http response

Tags: http, angular, httpresponse

I have a problem with angular2 http response.

I want to catch the error in my component.

How does my app work.
In my Component, I Call a function in a personal service :

```
var response = this.apiUser.login(username, password);
alert(response);
```

In my Service, I try to auth :

```
this.http.post(this.httpApiAdress + '/' + this.httpUserAutenticate, body, { headers: contentHeaders })
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.json().token);
                    this.router.navigate(['home']);
                },
                error => {
                    return error.json();
                },
                () => { }
            );
```

When the auth is ok, all work fine. But when the Auth fail, i can't catch the response in my Component.
(Its undefinied because the alert is executed before the http call...)

Can u help me please !!! (It was working when all the code was only in my Component, but I wanted to slip my code...)

Ty.

Comment: The code below "I try to auth" is in the `apiUser.login() {...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the observable by using `map()` instead of `subscribe()`

```
return this.http.post(this.httpApiAdress + '/' + this.httpUserAutenticate, body, { headers: contentHeaders })
.map(
    response => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.json().token);
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
    },
);
```

and then use subscribe where you want to execute code when the response or error arrives

```
    var response = this.apiUser.login(username, password)
    .subscribe(
        response => alert(response), 
        error => alert(error),
    );
```

Comment: You're THE man ! I tried to do this since 3 hours... And here u come... Ty Mate !